# Get class with highest score

Tags: python, tensorflow

I use the following code to get predictions.

```
for node_id in top_k:
    score = predictions[0][node_id]
    human_string = label_lines[node_id]
    print('%s (score = %.5f)' % (human_string, score))
```

The above code prints predictions with scores for all classes. however, How do I get the label with highest score?

Comment: can you add some sample data?

Comment: There is a lot of code missing here to make assumptions with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solutions using `max`

```
score, key = max((v, k) for k, v in predictions[0].items())
print('{} (score = {:.5f})'.format(label_lines[key], score))
```